# NullPointerException addToRequestQueue(com.android.volley.Request, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using [AndroidHive register login](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) and it's working fine in example project of this login-register.

But after many attempts trying it with `CardView`s and other widgets, this error appears on the `LogCat`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void client.myproject.app.AppController.addToRequestQueue(com.android.volley.Request, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at client.myproject.RegisterActivity.registerUser(RegisterActivity.java:185)
            at client.myproject.RegisterActivity.access$300(RegisterActivity.java:35)
            at client.myproject.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:81)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

While these codes works fine in a single app (just with register login).

I'm using Volley library.

Comment: Did you add AppController to the AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` add

```
<application android:name="YOURPACKAGENAME.AppController" 
             android:allowbackup="true" 
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: It's because of `AppController`, which extends `Application`.

Comment: Here you can read what `Application` is used for: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. But I am making login and registration process in the middle of app. So I can not add it in the application tag. I tried adding it to the activity tag but still the same error. Any help ?

Comment: WHAT A BOSS. Worked.

Answer (score 7):

As N1to says, you need to add your controller in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, if you don't add it then the `onCreate()` is never called and when you call `AppController.getInstance()` the instance is null.

```
<application android:name="YOURPACKAGENAME.AppController" 
         android:allowbackup="true" 
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

It also works for me with:

```
<application android:name=".AppController" 
         android:allowbackup="true" 
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I forgot to initialize the variable rq, please, make sure you did it

```
    ...
    private RequestQueue rq;   // rq = null (NullPointerException if you use it)
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(YourActivity.this);  // rq != null
    }
    ...
    rq.add(request);
```

Answer (score 3):

In menifest file add appcontroller as shown

```
<application android:name="app.AppController" 
         android:allowbackup="true" 
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you've initialized your requestQueue object as :

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass any data to the volley method, that means it get null data (empty data).....
see example:

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();
                map.put(region, regionName);
                return map;
            }
```

if regionName is empty it will give you NullPointerException, so regionName must have something.....

Answer (score 0):

try this inside onCreate()

```
requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error because i have mistakenly referenced the **wrong xml file** in `onCreate` method

// R.layout.activity_calender should be the same xml file of your activity (CalenderActivity)
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_calender);`