# I am not able to post data to Mysql database using Volley library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

Here is the volley code which is throwing following exception 
"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()".

```
String url = "http://192.168.60.02/TransportTracking/main.php";

StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // response
                Log.d("Response", response);
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // error
                Log.d("Error.Response", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
    {
        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("long","100");
        params.put("lat", "200");
        params.put("recordtime","acbcbcb");

        return params;
    }
};
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest, "tag_json_obj");
```

and Here is the Log of error:

07-06 08:07:54.315 2837-2837/com.example.jawadtariq.uogtransporttrackingsystem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                 Process: com.example.jawadtariq.uogtransporttrackingsystem, PID: 2837

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                        at com.android.volley.Request.(Request.java:136)
>                                                                                                        at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.(StringRequest.java:43)

```
                                                                                                 at com.example.jawadtariq.uogtransporttrackingsystem.LocationService$3.<init>(LocationService.java:98)
                                                                                                 at com.example.jawadtariq.uogtransporttrackingsystem.LocationService.onConnected(LocationService.java:81)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzn(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbco.zzm(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcc.zzpY(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcc.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcw.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbbh.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zzrj(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzs(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzrk(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

One last thing to mention is that I have googled this exception before posting here and most of the problem questions have incorrect URL. But in my case URL is correct.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31302011/5180017)  for.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a instance of volley request-queue and then add a stringRequest in it.
like

```
RequestQueue requestQueue =  
             Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // response
                Log.d("Response", response);
        }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // error
                Log.d("Error.Response", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    ){
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
    {
        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("long","100");
        params.put("lat", "200");
        params.put("recordtime","acbcbcb");
        return params;
    }
};

requestQueue.add(postRequest);
```

This is working code for me.

Comment: But i am using volley singleton class and my code compiled but is throwing a exception as mentioned above

Comment: If you have host your url at locally then try it with 127.0.0.1 for android devices and 10.0.2.2 for AVD devices. Make sure your PC and devices are in same connection. @jawad..