# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo : Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, qr-code, barcode-scanner

This is a barcode scanning app. It crashes when I scanned the code. If anyone knows how to fix help me out.

It crashes after I scanned the code from the `ScanActivity.java` and pass the object to the `TicketResultActivity.java`to display the result.

**error**

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.movietickets/info.androidhive.movietickets.TicketResultActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void info.androidhive.movietickets.MyApplication.addToRequestQueue(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // making toolbar transparent
        transparentToolbar();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_scan).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScanActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void transparentToolbar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, true);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    private void setWindowFlag(Activity activity, final int bits, boolean on) {
        Window win = activity.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
        if (on) {
            winParams.flags |= bits;
        } else {
            winParams.flags &= ~bits;
        }
        win.setAttributes(winParams);
    }
}
```

**ScanActivity.java**

```
public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BarcodeReader.BarcodeReaderListener{

    BarcodeReader barcodeReader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);

        // get the barcode reader instance
        barcodeReader = (BarcodeReader) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.barcode_scanner);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanned(Barcode barcode) {

        // playing barcode reader beep sound
        barcodeReader.playBeep();

        // ticket details activity by passing barcode
        Intent intent = new Intent(ScanActivity.this, TicketResultActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("code", barcode.displayValue);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScannedMultiple(List<Barcode> list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapScanned(SparseArray<Barcode> sparseArray) {

    }

    /*@Override
    public void onCameraPermissionDenied() {
        finish();
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onScanError(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred while scanning " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**TicketResultActivity.java**

```
public class TicketResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = TicketResultActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // url to search barcode
    private static final String URL = "https://api.androidhive.info/barcodes/search.php?code=";

    private TextView txtName, txtDuration, txtDirector, txtGenre, txtRating, txtPrice, txtError;
    private ImageView imgPoster;
    private Button btnBuy;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TicketView ticketView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ticket_result);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        txtName = findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtDirector = findViewById(R.id.director);
        txtDuration = findViewById(R.id.duration);
        txtPrice = findViewById(R.id.price);
        txtRating = findViewById(R.id.rating);
        imgPoster = findViewById(R.id.poster);
        txtGenre = findViewById(R.id.genre);
        btnBuy = findViewById(R.id.btn_buy);
        imgPoster = findViewById(R.id.poster);
        txtError = findViewById(R.id.txt_error);
        ticketView = findViewById(R.id.layout_ticket);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        String barcode = getIntent().getStringExtra("code");

        // close the activity in case of empty barcode
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(barcode)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Barcode is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

        // search the barcode
        searchBarcode(barcode);
    }

    /**
     * Searches the barcode by making HTTP call
     * Request was made using Volley network library but the library is
     * not suggested in production, consider using Retrofit
     */
    private void searchBarcode(String barcode) {
        // making volley's json request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL + barcode, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Ticket response: " + response.toString());

                        // check for success status
                        if (!response.has("error")) {
                            // received movie response
                            renderMovie(response);
                        } else {
                            // no movie found
                            showNoTicket();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                showNoTicket();
            }
        });

        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

    }

    private void showNoTicket() {
        txtError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ticketView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    /**
     * Rendering movie details on the ticket
     */
    private void renderMovie(JSONObject response) {
        try {

            // converting json to movie object
            Movie movie = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), Movie.class);

            if (movie != null) {
                txtName.setText(movie.getName());
                txtDirector.setText(movie.getDirector());
                txtDuration.setText(movie.getDuration());
                txtGenre.setText(movie.getGenre());
                txtRating.setText("" + movie.getRating());
                txtPrice.setText(movie.getPrice());
                Glide.with(this).load(movie.getPoster()).into(imgPoster);

                if (movie.isReleased()) {
                    btnBuy.setText(getString(R.string.btn_buy_now));
                    btnBuy.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                } else {
                    btnBuy.setText(getString(R.string.btn_coming_soon));
                    btnBuy.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.btn_disabled));
                }
                ticketView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // movie not found
                showNoTicket();
            }
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "JSON Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            showNoTicket();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred. Check your LogCat for full report", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // exception
            showNoTicket();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred. Check your LogCat for full report", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class Movie {
        String name;
        String director;
        String poster;
        String duration;
        String genre;
        String price;
        float rating;

        @SerializedName("released")
        boolean isReleased;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getDirector() {
            return director;
        }

        public String getPoster() {
            return poster;
        }

        public String getDuration() {
            return duration;
        }

        public String getGenre() {
            return genre;
        }

        public String getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public float getRating() {
            return rating;
        }

        public boolean isReleased() {
            return isReleased;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add MyApplication to android manifest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302011/nullpointerexception-addtorequestqueuecom-android-volley-request-java-lang-str follow this link

Comment: Thank you @Jeeva for your help. I didn't know that I have to add that in my Manifest. Now it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize `MyApplication` properly you have to add the following in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application android:name="com.package.subpackage.MyApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't know I have to add that. Now it works. Thank you for your help.